# Deploy Laravel on Google App engine - base_path() wrong

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine

I am deploying my Laravel app on Google Cloud App Engine.

Everything is working fine.

Howerver, I noticed that `base_path()` returns `/app`. I thought `base_path()` returns the root folder of the app.

Does App Engine wrap the application within a `app` folder somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is because you dont specify a `APP_STORAGE` environment variable , it then defaults to /app dir.

From laravel docs
[Laravel installation guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjFMZ.png)

Follow the boilerplate and see if it helps you at [GCP - Laravel GAE Standard](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-standard)

TLDR; reference app.yaml file

```
runtime: php72

env_variables:
  APP_KEY: YOUR_APP_KEY
  APP_STORAGE: /tmp
  VIEW_COMPILED_PATH: /tmp
  SESSION_DRIVER: cookie
```

Comment: Thanks @borrelito. I am using Flex not Standard on Google Cloud. Do I still need to configure that?

Comment: Yes it should listen to these aswell same as for standard

Comment: APP_STORAGE I can confirm has no usage under flex environment. Setting a value for this env variable kept the base_path() as app.